# PDF viewer (Skim) not opening or updating on build with Sublime Text 4 and LaTeXTools on Mac

Tags: pdf, mactex, viewers, sublime-text, latextools

I recently downloaded the new Sublime Text 4 version on a Mac and manually set up LaTeXTools, MacTeX, and Skim using the documentation provided here: https://latextools.readthedocs.io/en/v3.13.0/README/

I understand that Sublime Text 4 isn't officially supported by LaTeXTools yet, but I thought I'd give it a go. The LaTeX system works normally. Both pdfLateX and LuaLateX/XeLaTeX generate PDFs, the traditional and basic builders both work fine, and both bibTeX and bibLaTeX (with a Biber backend) function normally. The only thing that doesn't work is Skim. It won't open itself when a new PDF is built while it's closed, and it won't update when a new PDF is built while it's open. I made sure to edit the sync functionality as instructed in the README (see above link) and I've double-checked that Skim opens a PDF when I invoke the 'open -a Skim.app' command (as found in Preferences -> Package Settings -> LateXTools -> Settings - Advanced, "open_image_command" ) in a terminal.

I'm not really a LaTeX or Sublime Text wizard, and I only have a cursory knowledge of how a package like LaTeXTools works, so I don't have any idea where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm not sure if that question is on topic here ...

Comment: Oops. I can move it if I need to. Which site would be better?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, let us see if someone here can answer it. I do not use Sublime ...

Comment: I do not have the reputation to add comments or vote, but I would like to say that updating skim to 1.6.8 solved this issue for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading to Monterey (12.1). I tried a solution proposed here:

https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/issues/1553#issuecomment-999511000

but it did not help. I used ST4 (build 4126) and Skim 1.6.7. Today, Skim asked me to update to 1.6.8. I did and now the problem is gone!

I had used 1.6.8 before and it did not work. So, the sequence of events that lead to this result is: (1) get rid of Skim; (2) download and install Skim 1.6.7; (3) ask Skim to check for an update and install 1.6.8.

I have no idea whatsoever to explain this outcome.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).